# How to show the selected/Checked items after clicking anywhere outside the control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I want to show the selected items once i click outside of the drodowncombobox(Radcombobox). Which event shall i call to perform it?

Here is my code:

```
private static void ShowCheckedItems(RadComboBox comboBox, Literal literal)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var collection = comboBox.CheckedItems;

        if ( collection.Count != 0 )
        {
            sb.Append("<h3>Checked Items:</h3><ul class=\"results\">");

            foreach ( var item in collection )
                sb.Append("<li>" + item.Text + "</li>");

            sb.Append( "</ul>" );

            literal.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            literal.Text = "<p>No items selected</p>";
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowCheckedItems(RadComboBox1, itemsClientSide);
    }
```

In the above code, the action is executed based on a button click. But i want to show the same effect on clicking outside of the RadComboBox1.
Here is the html code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <%--<telerik:RadSkinManager ID="RadSkinManager1" runat="server" ShowChooser="true" />--%>
    <telerik:RadFormDecorator ID="FormDecorator1" runat="server" Skin="Metro" />
    <div class="qsf-demo-canvas">
        <div class="continents">
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" Width="186px"
                AutoPostBack="true" EmptyMessage="- Select a Country -"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                Skin="Metro">
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
        </div>
        <div class="countries">
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox2" runat="server" Width="186px"
                AutoPostBack="true" EmptyMessage="- Select a City -"
                CheckBoxes="true"
                EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true"
                Skin="Metro">
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
        </div>
        <p class="buttons">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Explore" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </p>
        <div class="result">
            <asp:Literal ID="itemsClientSide" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadComboBox1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadComboBox2" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Put your JavaScript code here.
    </script>
    <div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: using `jquery`? If **yes** then post your html or create a demo!!

Comment: I have added the html code in the edit.

Comment: That ain't `html`!! `html` in the sense what gets rendered in browser!! This contains **Telrik** controls and its hard to identify what gets generated from here!! Good if you create a demo!!